# Team Foundation 2013 + Sharepoint - strange behaviour

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server, dashboard, sharepoint-2013

[image: main image]

I just update my TFS 2010 + Sharepoint to TFS 2013 + Sharepoint foundation.

Everything is ok, I created a website, collections, documents and everything.

When I linked the TFS project collection to the website I noticed different website styles between the Sharepoint section (collections, libraries and so on ) and the project dashboard (it seems it is using the 2010 version).
[take a look at the image above, left side]

There's a new "Issues" section that isn't related to TFS.

If I click "team web access" the 2013 version of TFS dashboard appears:

[image: tfs only]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sounds like the sharepoint site upgrade failed to upgrade several site files, and when you access those files, you see 2010 content, instead of what should be a new 2013 page. just a guess though.

Comment: That's a new install using backup databases (hardware failure); the strange things is that the TFS portal is fully updated

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 includes both the new engine and the 2010 engine.  SharePoint database upgrades from 2010 to 2013 will default to 2010 styles.

In SharePoint- go to site settings.  Under Site Collection Administration there should be a link to upgrade the site.  Click it and follow the directions to upgrade to the 2013 site experience. You will have an option to preview the site - but I'm not sure how that will work with TFS integration (I suspect the site will work, but TFS part won't).  I would backup your database (holding the SharePoint site) and just run with the full upgrade. The rollback plan is to restore your database.

Let me know if you have any problems.